# Return to call UI when incoming call activity put in background

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, call

I am working on a custom calling app in which I have to put a UI when the user put the app in the background during the incoming call. I am showing notification but my IncomingCallActivity not resumed.
Is it possible to place a UI "return to call" over all apps during an incoming call?

Code for notification is below:

```
private void createNotification() { 
    // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IncomingCallActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pref_noti_icon)
            .setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_return_to_call))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);


    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Dear @ADM I have edited my question, now seems it is pointing my real issue. Please consider retract downvote. Thankyou

Comment: You don't need to place `"return to call` on Window . Just provide `PendingIntent` for Activity and it will open the same InCallActivity onClick of notification . Make sure you are using proper launchMode for  InCallActivity  . Also you should use action with notification to hangup the call . just take reference from any System Phone APP.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed issue by updating my code as below:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (!isNotificationShown)
    createNotification();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isNotificationShown) {
        clearNotification();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
        clearNotification();
}

//Create Notification
private void createNotification() {
    isNotificationShown = true;
    createNotificationChannel();
    // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent intent = new Intent(IncomingCallActivity.this, IncomingCallActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pref_noti_icon)
            .setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_return_to_call))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}

private void clearNotification() {
    isNotificationShown = false;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (notificationManager!=null)
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
```

Also don't forget to set `android:launchMode="singleTop"` of *Activity* in *AndroidManifest.xml* file.